# What does the term empirical praxis mean?

Tags: meaning

I don't know why but more than often I am encountering the phrase *"empirical praxis"*.

Does its meaning have any relation to the phrase "empirical truth" ? What is it exactly about ?

Sample usage -

> More and more companies are discovering that empirical praxis is the only long term energy supply in business.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase you have quoted seems to come from [this Quora post](http://acceptingpayments.quora.com/The-Time-Has-Come-To-Say-This-Publicly). The post is praising a particular person as a visionary.

The meaning of *empirical praxis*, in this context, seems to be something like "well researched practices". The author is using purple prose because of their deep admiration of the person they think is a visionary. I would say *practice* is the more usual word to use in this context.

Comment: Haha. 
Nice investigative skills Mr.Sherlock ;)